# Instructional ArcGIS Online resources in Arabic or Farsi or Pashto or Turkish?

Tags: arcgis-online, education, internationalization, arabic

I work for a school district with a wide variety of immigrants and quite a few refugees. Many children come in not knowing any English or very limited.

I have found that maps transcend language barriers but on ArcGIS Online the resources are in English, German, Spanish, French, Japanese, Simplified Chinese, and Russian.  I would like to get some instructional lessons in other languages with the idea of allowing everyone to participate in making a Story Map or other web map (we have Chrome books and the Esri K-12 free license to work with). I think the product could be a beautiful map with as much English writing as they can handle but still conveying an idea/story.

I know GIS analysts come from all over the world, so I am crossing my fingers I can get some advice on what to look for translated/new materials (my previous search came up with ArcGIS youtube videos in Arabic but those were for desktop)

Comment: I would suggest you contact the education team at Esri directly